# How to kill a pseudoterminal

Tags: login, logout

The **users** command lists my username four times.  I understand that's the result of (unintentional) multiple logins.  But how do I close out all but one of them?  Simply logging out doesn't seem to do it. I think I might have to get to the right pseudoterminal, but how do I do that -- especially aftere a reboot?

Comment: The file `var/run/utmp`might give you some hints.

Comment: It seems to contain gibberish -- no readable text.

Answer (score 0):

You can see what pseudoterminals you're using with the **w** commmand. To kill a particular one, use **pkill -9 -t pts/** *n*. But the behavior is a little funky if you try to kill the pseudotermnal where you're running the **w** command.

This also doesn't seem to remove duplicates in the result of **w**.  I haven't been able to reduce the number of pseudoterminals to less than 2 (plus **tty1**).